# IE Readystate stuck at 1 during VBA webscraping

Tags: vba, web-scraping, readystate

When attempting to reach a URL my code gets stuck in my readystate loop and never loads. The readystate remains at 1 permanently. If I pause the code and hit debug the cursor skips around my procedure in a bizarre order, sometimes to the end then to the beginning, sometimes right back to the beginning of the sub.

I read that this might be an issue with the javascript but I can't seem to find any resolution.

Is there a way to get this to work?

```
Sub Navigate()

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate ("http://web.vermont.org/Accounting?ysort=true")

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
           DoEvents
    Loop


    Set Doc = IE.Document

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That server seems to respond quite nicely to XML requests and does not require that you move to subsequent pages for the remainder for the content.

```
Sub Get_Listings()
    Dim sURL As String, iDIV As Long, htmlBDY As HTMLDocument, xmlHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    Set xmlHTTP = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Set htmlBDY = New HTMLDocument

    'sURL = "http://web.vermont.org/Accounting?ysort=true"
    sURL = "http://web.vermont.org/Dining?ysort=true"


    With xmlHTTP
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        .send
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        If .Status <> 200 Then GoTo CleanUp
        htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With htmlBDY
        For iDIV = 0 To (.getElementsByclassname("ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLELEFTBOX").Length - 1)
            If CBool(.getElementsByclassname("ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLELEFTBOX")(iDIV).getElementsByTagName("a").Length) Then
                Debug.Print _
                  .getElementsByclassname("ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLELEFTBOX")(iDIV).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innertext
            End If
        Next iDIV
    End With

CleanUp:
    Set htmlBDY = Nothing
    Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will need Microsoft XML 6.0, Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet Controls added to Tools, References. I'm offering this snippet as I could find no Terms of Use on that site that banned the use of robotic scrapers. Be careful that you do not get your IP banned due to repetitive scraping requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am a complete novice at this and still just learning my way around.

I am not familiar with using XML in this way. Can you recommend a site or how-to that I can read up on it?

Comment: @Mike - This is as good a site as any but you should narrow your initial searches to something like [XMLHTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=XMLHTTP). Version specific issues can be resolved after you get the initial concepts and start building blank code models that you can reuse for multiple purposes.